# I have no idea how the after method for tkinter works

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm trying to make an intercom in python just for fun.

I want it to write "Err" and blink for 5 seconds when you try to call a number more than 69.
But `time.sleep()` won't work in tkinter and I don't know how to work with the `.after()` method.

```
    if int(lbl.cget("text"))>69:
    for i in range(5):
        lbl.configure(text="Err")
        time.sleep(0.5)
        lbl.configure(text="     ")
        time.sleep(0.5)
```

Comment: Then you should read the documentation for `after()`.

Comment: In short `after()` executes a function after a given time period (approximate) not delay something

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `.after()` to execute a function every half second to toggle the text of the label:

```py
def do_blink(lbl, n=10):
    if n > 0:
        lbl.after(500, do_blink, lbl, n-1) # call again after half a second
        lbl["text"] = "" if n&1 else "Err" # toggle between "" and "Err"

if int(lbl["text"]) > 69:
    do_blink(lbl)
```